Changing tabular option with l3keys
In the following implementation I am using w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim}, but I also want to have the option of using l instead.  Could I just replace w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim} with an l, or is it better to have a separate tabular call ?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RequirePackage {array}

\dim_new:N \l_ditura_width_dim
\tl_new:N \l_ditura_width_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_ditura }
  {
    width .dim_set:N = \l_ditura_width_dim,
    width .initial:n = 8cm,
    %% width .default:n = ,
    width .value_required:n = false,
    width .usage = general,        

    name .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_name_tl,
    name .initial:n = ,
    %% name .default:n = ,
    name .value_required:n = false,
    name .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\ditura} { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_ditura} {#1}

    \begin {tabular} { @{} w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim} @{} }
      \l_ditura_name_tl
    \end {tabular}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}}
\ditura {name={Frillu Grillu}}

\end {document}

Have been introspecting the following solution
\tl_new:N \l_ditura_colspec_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ditura_colspec:n
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        {l} { \tl_set:Nn \l_ditura_colspec_tl { l } }
        {w} { \tl_set:Nn \l_ditura_colspec_tl { w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim} } }
      }
        {
          \tl_set:Nn \l_ditura_colspec_tl { l }
        }
  }


given you have width .initial:n = 8cm, you can't default to natural size, so what input syntax do you want?

In case an l is requested, I will have to disregard width.

I could use a boolean option fixat that applies fixed width declaration.

Haw difficult is it to construct the tabular option with a tl variable which is either set to l or w{l}{\l_ditura_width_dim} as input to tabular ?

I would use default not initial to set the 8cm then you can use absence of the key to imply natural width (l) and use of the key with no value to imply the default 8cm width.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage {array}

\ExplSyntaxOn



\tl_new:N \l_ditura_width_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_ditura }
  {
    width .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_width_tl,
    width .default:n = 8cm, % not initial
  
    name .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_name_tl,
    name .initial:n = ,
    %% name .default:n = ,
    name .value_required:n = false,
    name .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\ditura} { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_ditura} {#1}
\ExpandArgs{ne}\begin {tabular} { @{}
                 \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_ditura_width_tl
                 {l}
                 {w{l}{\l_ditura_width_tl}}
                 @{} }
      \l_ditura_name_tl
      \end {tabular}
  \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

X\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}}X % natural width

X\ditura {name={Frillu Grillu}}X     %

\bigskip

X\ditura {width,name={Likku Cirillu}}X     % default 8cm

X\ditura {width,name={Frillu Grillu}}X     %

\bigskip

X\ditura {width=4cm,name={Likku Cirillu}}X     % specified 4cm

X\ditura {width=4cm,name={Frillu Grillu}}X     %

\bigskip



\end {document}


Why is @Skillmon using \exp_not:V whilst you aren't ?

@Bulldrive because I decided to let it expand and he did not. Either works in this case.

Why would one not let expansion for \l_ditura_width_dim ?

Does expansion not happen for { w {l} { \l_ditura_width_dim } } if one does not use \exp_args:Nne ?

@Bulldrive \exp_args:Nne and \ExpandArgs{ne} are the same thing. none of the tokens you list in { w {l} { \l_ditura_width_dim } }  but the main point of the expansion is to expand \tl_if_empty:NTF

Should I use \bool_if:NTF \l_ditura_fixed_width_bool (rather than \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_ditura_width_tl) would I still require \exp_args:Nne ?

@Bulldrive yes of course, you need to generate a valid tabular preamble.

Without that, will the\bool_if:NTF condition not be evaluated ?

This isn't how the site works. You could simply try it. But \bool_if:NTF is not a legal token in a array package tabular preamble as latex would report if you bothered to try.

Yes, I get ! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\bool_if:NTF): c' used.`.  But a latex report is not completely conducive to understanding what is going on. For me, anyway, the explanation is more important.

Instead of using a single key and tracking its state you could also add another key that switches to natural width:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_ditura_width_dim
\tl_new:N \l_ditura_width_tl

\keys_define:nn { kvi_ditura }
  {
    width .dim_set:N = \l_ditura_width_tl,
    width .initial:n = 8cm,
    %% width .default:n = ,
    width .value_required:n = false,
    width .usage = general,        

    natural-width .bool_set:N = \l_ditura_natural_width_bool,

    name .tl_set:N = \l_ditura_name_tl,
    name .initial:n = ,
    %% name .default:n = ,
    name .value_required:n = false,
    name .usage = general,
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\ditura} { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_ditura} {#1}

    \exp_args:Nne \begin {tabular}
      {
        @{}
        \bool_if:NTF \l_ditura_natural_width_bool
          { l }
          { w {l} { \exp_not:V \l_ditura_width_tl } }
        @{}
      }
      \l_ditura_name_tl
    \end {tabular}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

x\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}}x

x\ditura {name={Frillu Grillu}}x

\SetKeys[kvi_ditura]{natural-width=true}

x\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}}x

x\ditura {name={Frillu Grillu}}x

\end {document}



Why are you using \exp_not:V ?

@Bulldrive same reason why I'd stick with tl instead of dim: What if there are contents there that might change depending on context. With the \exp_not:V it's just cleaner, the table gets exactly what the user input (but admittedly the list of circumstances I could think of where this actually makes a difference are rather few).

@Bulldrive though with the dim instead of the tl it really made no sense, I corrected that.

The value is already in the correct form when using \l_ditura_width_dim.

@Bulldrive "though with the dim instead of tl it really made no sense, I corrected that."
